# Prove continuity of function from normed space to real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, normed-spaces

I only know how to show the continuity or discontinuity of a function from a metric space to $\mathbb{R}$. Now I have to show continuity of a function from a normed space $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, every normed space is a metric space with $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. So, you can use all your metric space technology.

Here are two (of many) equivalent definitions for continuity in this setup.

A function $f: (X, \|\cdot\|) \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous when either of the two equivalent conditions hold:

1) Given any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $x \in X$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y \in X$ such that $\|x - y\| < \delta$, it holds that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon.$

2) Given any open subset $U \subset \Bbb{R}$, it holds that $f^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is open.